# Строки. Java. Замена слов в строке по количеству символов

Tags: java

Помогите написать метод который будет заменять все слова с определённой длинной.
Пользователь вводит длину слова 3, то все слова у который 3 символа должны замениться. Я не знаю как это реализовать.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        main.run();
    }

    private void run() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("STR: ");
        String str = scanner.nextLine();
        String newWord, oldWord;
        System.out.println("Слова которые нужно заменить");
        oldWord = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Слова которые нужно заменить");
        newWord = scanner.nextLine();
        String newStr = replaceWord(str,oldWord,newWord);
        System.out.println("новая строка" + newStr);
    }


    private String replaceWord(String str, String oldWord, String newWord) {
        return str.replaceAll(oldWord,newWord);

    }
}
```

Comment: В Вашей задаче четыре предложения. Выполняйте их по одному и задайте вопрос по первому из них, которое не получится реализовать. Так получится точный вопрос. Пока вопроса нет, получается, Вы просто просите выполнить за Вас задание, что нехорошо. Например: ввод текста в коде уже вроде есть, ввод слова для замены тоже, а вот длина слов нигде не принимается. Вы не знаете как ввести длину? Тогда оставьте только эту часть в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На java 8 можно, например так

```
public String replaceByLen(String sourceStr, int wordToReplaceLen, String newStr) {
    return Arrays.stream(sourceStr.split(" "))
            .map(str -> str.length() == wordToReplaceLen ? newStr : str)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

здесь слова делятся по пробелу, т.е. двойной пробел будет рассматриваться как "слово, включающее сивол пробела и пробел после этого слова"

Answer (score 0):

Используя регулярные выражения можно реализовать следующим образом

```
private String replaceWords(String s, String replacement, int length) {
   return s.replaceAll(String.format("\\b\\w{%d}\\b", length), replacement);
}
```